# Fields/custom text show translated label for field

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I am building a bilingual site with Drupal 10 and I am using views to show content items listings. In my views I am using field: Custom text to format the teasers of each item the way I want.

I have translated all the fields of my content types and my issue is how to show in the custom text each field's label.

Here is how my view's configuration looks like:
[image]

Here is an example of such a custom text:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 teaser-wrapper">
    <div class="teaser-image">{{ field_image }}</div>
    <div class="teaser-header">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="teaser-text">{{ body }}</div>
    <div class="row teaser-field">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 teaser-field">
                <span class="lbl">Location: </span>
                <span class="val">{{ field_region }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 teaser-field">
                <span class="lbl">Path Length: </span>
                <span class="val">{{ field_path_length }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 teaser-field">
                <span class="lbl">Activities: </span>
                <span class="val">{{ field_nature_activities }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see at the moment I am just using hardcoded values for the labels.

How can I print their translated values?

Comment: Have you tried `<span class="lbl">{{ 'Location'|t }}: </span>`?

Comment: No, but what exactly 'Location' is supposed to be? I have tried with using custom field's label (which is translated) without luck.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted. Some of us are new to Drupal; so do you expect from us to be able in a couple of months to have deep knowledge on all of it's aspects and different concepts? Does my question show lack of effort or is not clear? I have searched the web for an answer and read dozens of posts and documents relevant with Drupal views before posting. Why do "you" penalize people for asking when their aim is just to acquire knowledge? Have "you" born with the knowledge or is it a privilege that you need to pay in order to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<span class="lbl">{% trans %}Location{% endtrans %}: </span>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what exactly 'Location' is supposed to be? Original's custom field label? A custom label that I can create somehow and then translate?

Comment: Yes, a custom label from your question code. You can translate it

Comment: Thanks, I will try it